# Is there a breed of owl that makes a good pet

Tags: birds, pet-selection

Very much as the question says, is there a breed of owl that does well in a household environment?

[The barn owl trust](http://www.barnowltrust.org.uk/captive-barn-owls/) says that barn owls don't make good pets, but is there a breed that does, and what sort of environment should they be provided with?

Comment: In which country? In the US, I believe special permits are required to keep birds of prey.

Comment: @keshlam UK, for me, but I was hoping for a territory free answer about the birds themselves, as I think it's ok to keep owls without a permit here

Comment: Have you tried calling the barn owl trust?  They might well be able to give you some information or resources for further investigation - the odds are that the barn owl behaviour listed on your linked site will also apply to other species of owls.